# Should I always start an array from index 0? What should I do if I have to start elsewhere?

Tags: c

For a problem what I should write in my c code is:

```
for (i=min ; i<=max ; i++)   b[i]=i;
```

But my compiler shows errors:

> ||warning: command line option '-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant' is valid  for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]|
>   C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\counting_sort.c||In function 'main':|
>   C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\counting_sort.c|13|error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Usually, because the first element is index 0, but sometimes that is inconvenient, in that case you have to make the array 1 element bigger. If you have defined `int b[max]` you will overflow the array, because you can only index up to `b[max-1]` legally.

Comment: Your question title does not match the error you are getting. the problem is that `b` is not an array at all.

Comment: It depends. When I'm using a circular buffer, I start from 1 since it's a little more difficult to tell when there are no elements in the buffer; and starting at 1 aligns nicely with the other parts of my work. It's definitely dependent on why you're using the Array; and for the vast majority of cases, you should start from zero (and let your maintenance programmer know if you decide not to).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, arrays in C are 0-based.  Always.  You have no control over this.

Normal loops over arrays in C always look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
    ... do something with arr[i] ...
```

Note that `i` runs from 0 to `max-1`.  Note that the condition is `<`, not `<=`.

If you want to think of the array as running from 1 to N, or from an arbitrary min to an arbitrary max, you can simulate that in various ways.  You can loop over "your" indices and convert them to "real" array indices inside the loop:

```
int min = 10;
int max = 20;
int arr[11];

for(i = min; i <= max; i++)
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, arr[i-min]);
```

Or you can loop over real indices and convert them to your own inside the loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int myindex = i + min;
    printf("%d: %d\n", myindex, arr[i]);
```

But code like this can be confusing, because you have to always keep track of the difference between "your" indices and the "real" ones, and it's easy to accidentally use one when you meant the other.

Of course in all of this you must be careful to ensure that the size of the array is appropriate for the actual min and max you're using.  And remember "fencepost" errors!  If your min is 10 and your max is 20, you need an array of size 11, not 10!  (That is, the size you need is usually `max - min + 1`.)

If you want to simulate a 1-based array, the other thing you can do is just allocate it one bigger than you need, and waste cell 0:

```
#define N 10
int arr[N+1];    /* +1 so can make 1-based */

for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    arr[i] = i;
```

This works fine, but it can also be considered somewhat risky, because it's easy to forget to allocate the array 1 bigger than it needs to be, and you may also confuse a later reader of your code, who will see you writing something like

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
```

and say "No! That's wrong! It should be `for(i = 0; i < N; i++)`!".

Answer (score -1):

You should always start with 0. With your for loop, change it to:

```
for (i=min ; i <max ; i++) b[i] = i;
```

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful changed `i <= max` to `i < max`,

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't notice that. But, it still is dubious, since value of max and min should be bounded for standard C!

Comment: How did I end up with -2 when my answer was exactly the same as above (and mine was first?)

Comment: @EvanCarslake It's not all about the points, you know.  The people who downvoted your answer had probably moved on to a different question by the time Paul Ogilve posted his answer.  But if it makes you feel any better, I've given Paul a downvote, too.

Comment: @SteveSummit // off topic, I completely agree, I only was looking for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

As an array has members 0...n-1 with n the number of elements (max in your case), you should write:

```
for (i=min ; i<max ; i++)   b[i]=i;
```

and of course you can start somewhere in the middle, for example `min= max/2;`.

Comment: If, say, `min` is 10 and `max` is 20, but the size of the array is 11 (as the OP might have thought was sufficient), this won't work, and doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Steve-summit, that is his problem; i.e. to understand that. He just went beyond the bounds by writing `i<=max` (note the `-`), of course assuming 0<=min and max<sizeof(arr). Don't qoute the obvious.